# Creating an excel macro to format data in an XLS file

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, xls

Im working on creating a Macro to clean up some raw data outputted into an XLS by some software and make it more readable and filterable etc..

The data is formatted in the following manner (there are about 25k lines formatted identically to this:
[Example of data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkWDU.png)

and I would like it to look something like 
[this: (Manually made as an example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgKpb.png)

I was hoping the wizards of stackoverflow would be able to help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in the 1st sheet, create a 2nd sheet and then the following should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cleanUpData()
  Dim sht2 As Worksheet: Set sht2 = Sheets(2)

  Dim r As Integer, r2 As Integer: r2 = 2
  With Sheets(1):
    sht2.Range("A1:J1").Value = .Range("A1:J1").Value
    For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row Step 5:
      sht2.Range("A" & r2 & ":J" & r2).Value = .Range("A" & r & ":J" & r).Value
      sht2.Cells(r2, "J").Value = .Cells(r + 1, "A").Value & " " & .Cells(r + 1, "B").Value
      r2 = r2 + 1
    Next
  End With

  sht2.Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```